# Shortest way to remove duplicate words from string

Tags: r, string, duplicates

I have this string:

```
x <- c("A B B C")

[1] "A B B C"
```

I am looking for the shortest way to get this:

```
[1] "A B C"
```

I have tried this:
[Removing duplicate words in a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283624/removing-duplicate-words-in-a-string-in-r)

```
paste(unique(x), collapse = ' ')

[1] "A B B C"
# does not work
```

Background:
In a dataframe column I want to count only the unique word counts.

Comment: You need to split based on your code `paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))), collapse = " ")#
[1] "A B C"`

Comment: @akrun That's perfect please post as answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `regex` based approach could be shorter - match the non-white space (`\\S+`) followed by a white space character (`\\s`), capture it, followed by one or more occurrence of the backreference, and in the replacement, specify the backreference to return only a single copy of the match

```
gsub("(\\S+\\s)\\1+", "\\1", x)
[1] "A B C"
```

---

Or may need to split the string with `strsplit`, `unlist`, get the `unique` and then `paste`

```
paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))), collapse = " ")
# [1] "A B C"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, based on `stringr::str_split`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

str_split(x, " ") %>% unlist %>% unique

#> [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case the duplicates are not following each other, also using `gsub`.

```
x <- c("A B B C")
gsub("\\b(\\S+)\\s+(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "A B C"

gsub("\\b(\\S+)\\s+(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)", "", "A B B A ABBA", perl=TRUE)
#[1] "B A ABBA"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ,

```
gsub("\\b(\\w+)(?:\\W+\\1\\b)+", "\\1", x)
```